Duda en Java , no sé si es error de código o configuración del editor
Estoy empezando a aprender Java , me han mandado un ejercicio en el que tengo que leer una cantidad "N" y luego introducir "N" números enteros. Además se pide imprimir el mayor, el menor y las veces que aparece cada uno.
Bien , yo lo he hecho con un bucle for , aparentemente el código está bien, pero cuando lo ejecuto no sale en la terminal y tampoco me avisa de ningún problema concreto en vscode.
Adjunto lo que me aparece en la terminal cuando lo ejecuto y el código en si, si alguien sabe a que se debe se lo agradezco muchísimo!
import java.util.Scanner;
public class primerEjerc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int numLeer, numActual;
        int max = 0, min = 0, contadorMax = 1, contadorMin = 1;
        System.out.println("Dime una cantidad de números que leer" + (numLeer = entrada.nextInt()));
        for (int i = 0; i < numLeer; i++) {

            System.out.println("Dime un número");
            numActual = entrada.nextInt();
            max = numActual;
            min = numActual;

            if (numActual > max) {  // los == :(
                max = numActual;
                contadorMax = 1;  // como es nuevo máximo , el contador se reinicia a 1
            } else if (numActual == max) {
                contadorMax++;
            }

            if (numActual < min) {
                min = numActual;
                contadorMin = 1;
            } else if (numActual == min) {
                contadorMin++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("El mayor número introducido ha sido el " + max + "y aparece " + contadorMax + " veces.");
        System.out.println("El menor número ha sido " + min + " y aparece " + contadorMin + " veces.");
    }
}

}

Es error tuyo :) Fijate la diferencia entre System.out.println("Dime una cantidad de números que leer" + (numLeer = entrada.nextInt())); y System.out.println("Dime una cantidad de números que leer"); numLeer = entrada.nextInt();. Es más: si ingresás un número con tu código actual (a pesar de que el output se muestra "en blanco"), vas a notar que después aparece el mensaje de Dime una cantidad (...) ¡Prueba siempre tu código!

Muchísimas gracias @padaleiana , imagino que el haber puesto el scanner dentro del mismo System.out.println() era lo que me estaba fallando , ahora ya me sale todo bien por la terminal y puedo corregir los errores del código, me queda mucho camino. Infinitas gracias!
